# set razor @Html.Hidden within javascript function

Tags: c#, javascript, razor, hidden

Is there way to set razor @HTML.Hidden control value within a JavaScript code block?

```
<tbody>

                    @Html.Hidden("customerID")
                    @if (Model != null)
                    {
                        var customers = Model.Customers.ToList();
                        for (var i = 0; i < customers.Count; i++)
                        {
                        <tr class="gradeX">
                            <td>
                                <a href="#"><span onclick="GetCustomerID()">@customers[i].CustomerId.ToString()</span></a>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="#">@customers[i].Name</a>
                            </td>                                
                        </tr>
                        }
                    }
                </tbody>
```

and my JavaScript block is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var globleCustomerId = null;

    function GetCustomerID() {

        globleCustomerId = $('#customerID').val();

        //globleCustomerId value should be set to @Html.Hidden()


    }
</script>
```

Within this JavaScript block I need to set globleCustomerId value to @Html.Hidden("customerID").

How to get that value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method:

```
$('#customerID').val('some value');
```

There are 2 overloads: the one that doesn't take any arguments and which allows you to read the value (and which is what you have shown in your question) and one that takes an argument and sets the value (the one I have shown in my answer).

---

UPDATE:

Apparently you are trying to put the value of the customer id that was clicked upon in the hidden field. In this case you could simply give a class to your span element:

```
<a href="#">
    <span class="customerId">
        @customers[i].CustomerId.ToString()
    </span>
</a>
```

and then simply subscribe to the click event of this element:

```
$(function() {
    $('.customerId').click(function() {
        $('#customerId').val($(this).text());
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response but my problem is getting that value in @HTML.Hidden control then I can use that value in something like this var productsList = Model.Products.ToList().Select(x => x.CustomerId == int.Parse(*that hidden field value goes here*)).ToList();

Comment: You want to use the value of the hidden field on the server? In this case you don't need any javascript at all. When the form containing this hidden field is submitted the value will automatically be sent.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to get value of current customer ID. There is a for loop which generates list of customers. If user clicks 4th customer then I need that customer ID set to the hidden field. Therefore I created that java script function then within it set that value to hidden field and now I'm wondering how to get that java script value to Html.Hidden field

Comment: Well, then simply use .val method. I have updated my answer to illustrate how.

Answer (score 2):

```
function GetCustomerID() {

    globleCustomerId = $('#customerID').val();

     //  Use this line to set the globleCustomerId value to @Html.Hidden() field

      $('#customerID').val(globleCustomerId);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

well pure Javascript version is ;

```
//set
document.getElementById("customerID").value = "new value";
//get
var customerIDValue = document.getElementById("customerID").value;
```